# Different ways of arranging books of two different kinds

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can $21$ books on English and $19$ books on German be placed in a row on a shelf so that two books on German may not be together?

If we arrange English books and then in-between or on sides, we place German books then we would have $22$ ways to place $19$ German books. So, $^{22}C_{19}=1540$ (GEGEGE....GEG)

But if we arrange German books and in-between or on sides, we place English books then we would have $20$ places to keep English books. (EGEGEG...GEE) And $21st$ book could be placed anywhere I guess. How to solve the question with this approach? I am unable to make any move.

Answer (score 1):

You have 40 spaces, 19 german and 21 english books.
The only way to arrange the books in the spaces satisfying the given condition would be to have the german books placed alternately between the english books, with two consecutive english books.

- The consecutive english books can be in any two consecutive positions. Hence there are C(2,21).39.2 possibilities to place the consecutive english books (the books can be any two of the 21, they can be placed in any of the 39 possible consecutive positions, in any order).
- You have 38 remaining positions to fill in the other 19 english books and the 19 german books. This can be done in C(19,38).19!.19! ways.

Hence, if all the english books are distinct and so are the german, you have C(2,21).39.2.C(19,38).19!.19! ways.